# How to put a breakpoint on an ASP.net databinding expression?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

i have a line of code that is throwing a *Specified cast is not valid* exception:

```
<%# DecimalToStringUsingUserLocale( (Decimal)Eval("HoursBooked") ) %>
```

i want to have a breakpoint on this line, so i can inspect the value of:

```
Eval("HoursBooked")
```

to see what type the underlying `Object` is. How can i do this?

How can i put a breakpoint on a databinding expression line?

---

### Workaround

Move presentation from the view to the controller:

```
<%# HoursBookedToStr(Eval("HoursBooked")) %>
```

and then in the ***code-behind*** file:

```
protected string HoursBookedToStr(Object objectFromEval)
{
   Decimal value = (Decimal)objectFromEval;
   return DecimalToStringUsingUserLocale(value);
}
```

and now i can put a breakpoint on the line:

```
Decimal value = (Decimal)objectFromEval;
```

> **Note**: Now i can solve my problem because i see the object is not of type `Decimal`, as i thought, but instead is of type `System.DBNull`

---

How can i put a breakpoint on a databinding expression line?

**Note**: Don't confuse the example with the question: placing breakpoints on databinding.

Comment: I **believe** this is an inherit advantage of code-behind vs. inline. IMHO, it is reasons like this that I prefer code-behind. I marked your question as a favorite, because I also want to know if it is possible.